# Adding Date into extension attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes

I am trying to add the date into an extension attribute in PowerShell AD account but get an error saying:

> Invalid type: System.Management.Automation.PSObject

and the parameter is the one being used below.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity tst_lawsonja -Add @{extensionAttribute15 = Get-Date}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the "extensionattribute" only accepts `string` data? Try converting your date `.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gvee is correct. The `extensionAttribute` attributes are text-only. Convert the date to text, then try to set it, like this:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity tst_lawsonja -Add @{extensionAttribute15 = (Get-Date).ToString()}
```

Note that `Add` will only work if the attribute is not set yet. If it is, you need to use `Replace`:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity tst_lawsonja -Replace @{extensionAttribute15 = (Get-Date).ToString()}
```

`Replace` will always work, even if the attribute is not set, so you may just want to use that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I try that it errors out saying multiple values were specified for an attribute that can only have one value, any ideas on this?

Comment: You tried it exactly as I wrote it? I tried it (only changing the `Identity`) and it worked for me without errors

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Now that I try it again, I get the same error. Let me see what I did differently earlier.

Comment: Yeah exactly how you wrote it, got the error, I changed add to replace and its worked now. Might just need to add a clear and then add again, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Oh, haha, yes. That explains why I'm getting the same error now when I didn't before. I'll update my answer.